# Celery and flask, same celery app instance

Tags: python, flask, celery, celerybeat

I'm trying to add and remove tasks dynamically from celery beat through a few flask endpoints. 
I created a simple project named myApp and a package called flaskr (yes, like the tutorial) with three files in it

```
myApp
    flaskr
        __init__.py
        routes.py
        tasks.py
    wsgi.py
```

This is the endpoint code

```py
@route_blueprint.route('/myApp/add_task')
def add():
    print(celery.conf.beat_schedule)
    print(hex(id(celery)))
    celery.add_periodic_task(10.0, tasks.add.s(55, 2), name='add every 10')
    print(celery.conf.beat_schedule)
    return ""
```

I go to the PyCharm console and from one of them I run gunicorn like this:

**gunicorn wsgi:app -b localhost:8000**

From another console tab I also run Celery like this

**celery -A flaskr.celery worker --loglevel=info**

And from another I run beat like this

**celery -A flaskr.celery beat -l=debug**

When I hit the endpoint, in the console I can see the task being added but beat never sends it.

I suspected that flask was setting the task is a differente celery_app instance so I put a print of the celery object that I was trying to modify and yes, it was a different one.

### This is from celery start

flaskr:0x110048978

```
 -------------- celery@MacBook-Pro.local v4.3.0 (rhubarb)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Darwin-18.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit 2019-08-26 17:19:47
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         flaskr:0x110048978
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/2
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/2
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

### And this is from the endpoint

0x101e31e80

### Question

I'm quite new with python but I guess it makes sense, because i'm triggering the same code from two different processes, one from the celery worker and the other one from flask/gunicorn, so they'll never see each other.

Is there a way to give flask access to the instance initialized from the celery command line instance or should I start the workers from inside flask? (I didn't see that in any documentation from celery nor flask)

---

### This is the full code

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery
import config

celery = Celery(__name__,
                backend=config.CELERY_BACKEND,
                broker=config.CELERY_BROKER,
                include=['flaskr.tasks'])


@celery.task
def asd(x, y):
    print('ADD')
    # raise exceptions.Retry(20)
    return x + y


def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__)

    from .routes import route_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(route_blueprint)

    return app
```

**tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from . import celery
import logging.config


logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger('myApp')


@celery.task
def add(x, y):
    print('ADD')
    # raise exceptions.Retry(20)
    return x + y


@celery.task(bind=True)
def see_you(self, x, y):
    logger.info('Log de see_you')
    print(x)
    # print("See you in ten seconds!")


print('Initializing from tasks')
print(hex(id(celery)))
print('beat schedule: ' + str(celery.conf.beat_schedule))
# celery.add_periodic_task(10.0, add.s(1, 2), name='add every 10')
# print(str(celery.conf.beat_schedule))
```

**routes.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint
import logging.config
from . import tasks
from . import celery


route_blueprint = Blueprint('route_blueprint', __name__,)

logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger('myApp')


@route_blueprint.route('/myApp/health')
def health():
    return "Health ok"


@route_blueprint.route('/myApp/add_task')
def add():
    print(celery.conf.beat_schedule)
    # tasks.add.delay(55, 2)
    print(hex(id(celery)))
    celery.add_periodic_task(10.0, tasks.add.s(55, 2), name='add every 10')
    print(celery.conf.beat_schedule)
    return "okkk"
```